# what is the path of a python data file when --root was used with pip install?

Tags: python, pip

When installing a python module with `pip install --root=$HOME mypackage`, it may also install data files in `etc/` or `usr/share`. The code from the `mypackage` module needs to know what argument was given to `--root` to locate the data file (for instance `$HOME/etc/mypackage.conf`) and read it. How can this be done ?

Comment: Im pretty sure you cannot ... (and probably should not also)

Comment: I'm confused, you're suggesting that it's a bad idea for a module / executable file to rely on a configuration file or something different ?

Comment: Config files should either reside within the module itself, or at a defined location in `$HOME`, which is defined on OS X, Linux, and Windows. They should certainly not be put in `/etc` or `/usr/share`, unless you are installing a standalone program, **not** a module that will live in `site-packages` or `dist-packages`.

Comment: *The code from the mypackage module needs to know what argument was given to --root*  It does not nor is there any way to know what was given to root as far as I know ... just use pyenv or something